# Fullscreen in all browsers using javascript and css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a page fullscreen and and show only specific elements in fullscreen and change the size etc of that element.
It seams to work in firefox but not in chrome, IE or others.

This is the javascript I used

```
function goFullScreen() { 
    if ( 
          
        /* Standard syntax */ 
        document.fullscreenEnabled ||  
                      
        /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */ 
        document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ||  
                      
        /* Firefox */ 
        document.mozFullScreenEnabled || 
                      
        /* IE/Edge */ 
        document.msFullscreenEnabled  
    ) { 

        elem = document.querySelector('#mapfull'); 
        elem.requestFullscreen(); 
    } 
    else { 
        console.log('Fullscreen not enabled') 
    } 
} 
            
document.getElementById('btnFullscreen').addEventListener('click', function() {
    goFullScreen();
});
```

and this is the css

```
#mapfull:-webkit-full-screen .canvasdiv{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#mapfull:-moz-full-screen .canvasdiv{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#mapfull:-ms-fullscreen .canvasdiv{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#mapfull:fullscreen .canvasdiv{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried with

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#mapfull'),
    rfs = elem.requestFullScreen
    || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen
    || elem.mozRequestFullScreen
    || elem.msRequestFullscreen

    rfs.call(elem)
```

instead of

```
elem = document.querySelector('#mapfull'); 
elem.requestFullscreen();
```

and put vw/vh insetead of % in the css...something like this

```
#mapfull:fullscreen .canvasdiv{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Full screen is the user's discretion, generally.

Comment: Thankfully this is at the power of the user, and not the website. Imagine going to various pages only to be thrown into fullscreen mode. Thats as bad as the days where popup whole windows were a thing.

Comment: It is at the power of the user. I'm making a browser game in php and i want to make the map fullscreen when the user clicks the fullscreen button.

Comment: Basically it works perfectly in Mozilla.  In chrome or other browsers it goes full screen but for the css to take effect i have to press f12 twice to enable and disable the browsers console.